# PHP dynamic include other .php files

Tags: php, html

I am new to php coding and I hope you can help a java-boy out of the trouble.

I try to include navigation menu and content dynamicly in the "index.php".
If Í test the code below, I only get the same index.php again, without changing the navigation menu, which should happen in my opinion, but maybe I don't know php good enough.

My **index.php** :

```
<?php
    //^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING
    error_reporting(E_ALL);    
    if (!defined("ABS_PATH"))define("ABS_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

    if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['role'] = "guest";
        $_SESSION['navi'] = "/view/navigation_guest.php";
        $_SESSION['content'] = "/view/content_login.php";
        $_SESSION['calendar'] = "/view/calendar.php";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Klausurplaner</title>

        <link href="view/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="frame">
            <div id="header">
                <?php
                    include_once "/view/header.php";
                ?>
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <div id="navi">
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                            include_once $_SESSION['navi'];
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="content">
                    <?php
                        include_once $_SESSION['content'];
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div id="calendar">
                    <?php
                        include_once $_SESSION['calendar'];
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </body>

</html>
```

If I try to modify the index.php with the following content, as stated above, I only get the same website again, without having the navigation menu changed.

The **content_login.php** :

```
<?php
    if (!defined("ABS_PATH"))define("ABS_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    include_once(ABS_PATH . "/Klausurplaner/Control/LoginControl.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">  

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Bitte loggen Sie sich ein.</h1>

        <form method="post" action="control/btnLoginClicked.php">
            <p1>Benutzername:</p1>
            <br>
            <input id="edt_username" type="text" size="25%"/>
            <br>

            <p1>Passwort:</p1>
            <br>
            <input id="edt_password" type="password" size="25%"/>
            <br><br>
                <input name="btn_login" type="submit" value="login" size="5%"/>
        </form>
        <br><br>

           <!-- <br><br>
            <a href="content_guest_newPassword.php">Passwort vergessen</a> 
            <!-- E-Mail an die eigene E-Mail-Adresse mit neuem PW -->
    </body>

</html>
```

The **btnLoginClicked.php** :

```
<?php
    if (!defined("ABS_PATH"))define("ABS_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

/**
 * @author Falk Libor
 * @version 1.0
 * 
 * Date: 19.03.2013
 */

if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
    $_SESSION['navi'] = "/view/navigation_admin.php";
    $path = ABS_PATH . "/Klausurplaner/index.php";
    header("Location: " . $path);
    exit();
}

?>
```

**Edit:** session_start() is now before the if-block, but somehow it now shows the "navigation_admin.php" instead of the defined "navigation_guest.php" before I clicked the "btn_login" in the "content_login.php".  Any thoughts?

Comment: `$_SESSION` doesn't exist til after `session_start()`.  Just so you know.  :)

Comment: cHao is right, btw you need to put `session_start()` at the very beginning of your PHP code, before _any_ output is made.

Comment: thanks all :) But some how its loading the admin navigation at start, not after I clicked the button to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `session_start` *before*

```
   session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {   
            $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['role'] = "guest";
            $_SESSION['navi'] = "/view/navigation_guest.php";
            $_SESSION['content'] = "/view/content_login.php";
            $_SESSION['calendar'] = "/view/calendar.php";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The $_SESSION array doesn't exist until you use session_start(), so before you start it, you will never get any value from session and you cannot add to it either.